# Java: write byte[] to file (missing bytes)

Tags: java, file, byte

I am experiencing some problems with my code.

When I try to write to file `byte[]` (eg. of length 173517) using the function `Files.write write` into file random bytes (eg. 3355) each time, I get a different value.

This is my code:

```
byte[] dataBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
byte[] cipByte = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
byte[] encr = Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipByte);
Files.write(Paths.get(encryptedFile.getAbsolutePath()), encr); //encr len = 173517
```

Answer (score 0):

From my tests, it seems the problem is not the Files.write. I managed to write an array of byte of size **94486449** without problems.
So possible problems for what is not going as expected:

- either the **cipher** is not doing what you expect and cipByte is of different size than expected.
- the encoder is not doing what you are expecting. Be carefull that if you call Base64.getEncoder.encode(cipByte), the resulting byte array will not of the size of cipByte, but will have a different size.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are checking the right `encryptedFile`?

Your snippet enriched with the missing parts produce a valid output.

```
byte[] dataBytes = "text to be encrypted".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] cipByte = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
byte[] encr = Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipByte);

File encryptedFile = new File("/tmp/in.enc");
Files.write(Paths.get(encryptedFile.getAbsolutePath()), encr);

System.out.println("encr length: " + encr.length);
System.out.println("file length: " + encryptedFile.length());
```

output

```
encr length: 32
file length: 32
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i think the problem lies with the server and sends invalid data :)